# Isolation level: Difference between dirty write and lost update

Tags: sql, database, transactions, dirty-write, lost-update

I'm reading [A Critique of ANSI SQL Isolation Levels](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-95-51.pdf)
 and get confused by the two definitions:

### Dirty write

> w1[x]...w2[x]...((c1 or a1) and (c2 or a2) in any order)

### Lost update

> r1[x]...w2[x]...w1[x]...c1

Doesn't the history definition of lost update include dirty write? (The w2[x]...w1[x] part). If yes then if we prevent dirty write we prevent lost update, right? I know this is clearly wrong but I don't understand why. Can anyone give some hints on what I misunderstood here? Many thanks!

I found [the article](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/02/24/a-critique-of-ansi-sql-isolation-levels/) explaining this example:

[image]

> There is no Dirty Write since T2 commits before T1 writes x.

But the definition of lost update does not require the 2nd write to happen after the first transaction commits, right?

Answer (score 5):

- **Dirty write** is that a transaction updates or deletes (overwrites) the uncommitted data which other transactions insert, update or delete.  *Basically, **dirty write** doesn't occur with all isolation levels in many databases.
- **Lost update** is that two transactions read the same row to update it but the first committed update is overwritten by the second committed update. *Basically, **lost update** doesn't occur in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level in many databases and **lost update** is prevented using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in **MySQL** and **PostgreSQL**.

***The difference between **dirty write** and **lost update** is that uncommitted data is overwritten or committed data is overwritten.***

For example, there is **`product` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`stock`** as shown below. *The stocks of the products decrease when customers buy the products.

#### `product` table:

| id | name | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Apple** | **10** |
| **2** | **Orange** | **20** |

**These steps below** shows **dirty write**:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2;`** **20** |  | **T1 reads `20` which is updated later to `13` because a customer buys 7 oranges.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2;`** **20** | **T2 reads `20` which is updated later to `16` because a customer buys 4 oranges.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE product SET stock = '13' WHERE id = 2;`** |  | **T1 updates `20` to `13`.** |
| **Step 6** |  | **`UPDATE product SET stock = '16' WHERE id = 2;`** | **T2 updates `13` to `16` before T1 commits.** #### *Dirty write occurs. |
| **Step 7** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |

**These steps below** shows **lost update**:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2;`** **20** |  | **T1 reads `20` which is updated later to `13` because a customer buys 7 oranges.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2;`** **20** | **T2 reads `20` which is updated later to `16` because a customer buys 4 oranges.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE product SET stock = '13' WHERE id = 2;`** |  | **T1 updates `20` to `13`.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`UPDATE product SET stock = '16' WHERE id = 2;`** | **T2 updates `13` to `16` after T1 commits.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### *Lost update occurs. |

Comment: This answer is partially true,in your example in order for dirty read problem to occur **transaction 2 must read uncommitted data** from transaction 1 or vice versa.

So you  must switch Step 4 with Step 5 and finally **transaction** **1 must be failed.**

Comment: If T2 runs after T1 committed, we cannot say T1's update is lost. Why ? why must be in concurrent context ?